# Setting Up Reverse Proxy on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, apache2, php, reverse-proxy

I have two Ubuntu 16.04 (LTS) instances on Amazon ec2.  They are on the same virtual private cloud.  I have LAMP installed on both and would like to be able to call a web page on one from a web page on the other.  With CentOS, I simply edit /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and append the following line

```
ProxyPass /app1/ http://10.0.1.27/
```

Then, after I restart apache with

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

I can simply enter the following code, on a web page of the current server

```
<li><a href="/app1/Whatever.php">Whatever</a></li>
```

and the web page Whatever.php, on the server with the private IP 10.0.1.27, is displayed on my browser when I click the Whatever button.

However, Ubuntu does not have a /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file.

I tried setting up a reverse proxy as outlined [here](https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/configure-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu/) and entered the following in the /etc/apache2/sites-available/proxy-host file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log    
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  # Servers to proxy the connection, or
  # List of application servers Usage
  ProxyPass /app/ http://10.0.1.27:8080/
  ProxyPass / http://10.0.1.110:8080/
  # ProxyPassReverse / http://server-ip-address:8080/
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

I then enter

```
sudo a2ensite proxy-ssl-host.conf
```

and get

```
 ERROR: Site proxy-ssl-host does not exist!
```

Then I enter

```
sudo a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/proxy-host
```

and get

```
ERROR: Site /etc/apache2/sites-available/proxy-host does not exist!
```

I then enter

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

However, when I click on the Whatever button, I now get a 404 error

```
Not Found

The requested URL /app/Dracula.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 52.207.143.84 Port 80
```

Comment: From my experience it's good practice to name your vhost configs with a `.conf` suffix, so I'd recommend to make that a habit. `a2ensite` should find the config regardless, so you might want to double check the file's name and location. Another thing you could look into are the configs stats. Do the owner, group, permissions differ from, say, the default vhost's config? Also, after you activated (or deactivated) a site, you need to reload Apache.

Comment: That works!  Thanks very much.  I noticed that I had made a file called /etc/apache2/sites-available/proxy-host (which I renamed to /etc/apache2/sites-available/proxy-host.conf) per your suggestion.  However, I then entered sudo a2ensite proxy-ssl-host.conf per https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/configure-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu/.  I did not noticed that the "-ssl" string was absent in the file name but present in the a2ensite call.  After making the change, I was prompted to reload apache which I did and it now works.  Thanks again,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to double check that the name of your config file and the file name you use in the `a2ensite` command are identical. For example, if your config is in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/my_vhost.conf`, a command like `a2ensite my-vhost.conf` won't work.

It's been good practice for a long time to give your vhost configs the extension `.conf`. With Apache 2.2 and earlier, that was optional, since Apache 2.4 (which is shipped with Ubuntu 16.04) the `.conf` extension is mandatory.

After you enabled (or disabled, for that matter) a vhost, you need to reload Apache.